# Get exact values filter in Elastic/Lucene

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

When querying Elastic with:

```
"query": { 
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "query_string": {
        "query": "data.payload.NSFILEID.num:1492141378",
        "analyze_wildcard": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
}
```

I get docs with data.payload.NSFILEID.num = 1492141378 and close ones.

Same behaviour with:

```
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
              "data.payload.NSFILEID.num": 1492141378
        }
    }
}
```

This field is indexed as number.

How could I get only exact ones?

Comment: add cotes just like this for the exact search \"data.payload.NSFILEID.num:1492141378\"

Comment: What analyser have you used on data.payload.NSFILEID.num?

Comment: @OllyCruickshank default analyzer